# Can you help me with my const_iterator inner class?

Tags: c++, iterator, constants

I'm trying to learn more about iterators in c++, so I build a class holder that contains a vector to int. Then I built an inner iterator sub-class and everything went fine. Then I thought I should build a const_iterator sub-class, and being the newbie, I cannot figure out how to make all of the const stuff work in my new sub-class.

```
class Holder
{
public:
    Holder(list<int> _mylist = list<int>()) : mylist(_mylist) {}
    class iterator;
    iterator begin() { return iter.begin(*this); }
    class iterator
    {
    public:
        iterator() {};
        iterator begin(Holder &h) {
            lit = h.mylist.begin();
            return *this;
        }
        int operator*() { return *lit; }
        iterator& operator++() { ++lit; return *this; }
    private:
        list<int>::iterator lit;
    };

    class const_iterator;
    const_iterator begin() const { return citer.begin(*this); }
    class const_iterator
    {
    public:
        const_iterator() {};
        const_iterator begin(const Holder &h) const {
            lit = h.mylist.begin();
            return *this;
        }
        int operator*() { return *lit; }
        const_iterator& operator++() { ++lit; return *this; }
    private:
        list<int>::const_iterator lit;
    };
private:
    list<int> mylist;
    iterator iter;
    const_iterator citer;
};
```

Specifically at line 28 "lit = h.mylist.begin()" I get the error "*No operator '=' matches these operands*" I know that I just don't understand the magic of **const**, but there are some situations that require const_iterators and I don't know how to fix it. Any help to get me out of my fog would be appreciated.

Comment: No, everything did not "went fine". There are many fundamental problems with the shown code. I think you're trying to go too fast. Slow down and focus on C++ basics, and learning how to correctly use the existing iterators from the existing containers in the C++ library. Once you truly understand how they work, you should be able to implement them yourself, but this is fundamentally wrong. There's no reason, for example, for a container to have some instance of one iterator, for some unclear purpose. None of the standard C++ containers do.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @SamVarshavchik. I have been exploring iterators for a while, and I originally wrote one where the constructor required a reference to the outer class, and it imploded on me. So, I decided to take another tack. My ultimate purpose has been to write my own implementation of an unordered_map (associative array) where I have both a vector and a list to iterate through. I wanted to be able to write an iterator that could contain both the vector iterator and the list iterator.

Comment: it is true that iterators generally have to have some kind of an internal reference to their containers, but that's neither here, nor there, when it comes to anyone's constructor. Iterators get created by their container's `begin`() and `end`() (and, perhaps, `find`() and some others). As such, these methods can do everything that's needed to construct a new instance of the appropriate iterator. Storing some instance of the iterator as part of the class itself, does not really accomplish anything useful, and only adds unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Thanks again for the comment @SamVarshavchik. I will try to think more about not storing a private instance of these iterators. At first blush it seemed like a potential solution to my problems.

Comment: Not quite sure why this received a down vote within a minute of posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking @SamVarshavchik and @zett42 suggestions, I have made some changes that seem to work for me.

```
class Holder
{
public:
    Holder(list<int> _mylist = list<int>()) : mylist(_mylist) {}
    class iterator;
    iterator begin() 
    { 
        iterator iter;
        iter.lit = mylist.begin();
        return iter;
    }
    class iterator
    {
    public:
        iterator() {};
        int operator*() { return *lit; }
        iterator& operator++() { ++lit; return *this; }
        friend class Holder;
    private:
        list<int>::iterator lit;
    };

    class const_iterator;
    const_iterator begin() const
    {
        const_iterator citer;
        citer.lit = mylist.begin();
        return citer;
    }
    class const_iterator
    {
    public:
        const_iterator() {};
        const_iterator(iterator it) : lit(it.lit) { }
        int operator*() const { return *lit; }
        const_iterator& operator++() { ++lit; return *this; }
        friend class Holder;
    private:
        list<int>::const_iterator lit;
    };

private:
    list<int> mylist;
};

int main()
{
    list<int> intList = { 1,2,3,4 };
    const Holder chold(intList);
    auto cit = chold.begin();
    cout << *++cit << endl;
    Holder hold(intList);
    auto ait = hold.begin();
    Holder::const_iterator it = hold.begin()
    ++it;
    cout << *++it << endl;
}
```

**No longer relevant -** I am still unsure as to why I am able to declare **const_iterator begin() const**, but define it as **const_iterator begin()** without the **const** keyword. But I am hoping this answer will help someone else.

Comment: A little suggestion: remove the `iterator::begin()` member functions. It is very unusual and confusing for an iterator to have a `begin()` member. Typically only containers have `begin()` and `end()` members. Instead, assign the `lit` member from `Holder::begin()`. Make `Holder` a friend of `iterator` and `const_iterator`, so it can access the private `lit` member.

Comment: Also `Holder::const_iterator` will need a conversion constructor that has a `Holder::iterator` parameter. Otherwise the following will not compile: `Holder h; Holder::const_iterator it = h.begin();`